# Keep hitting !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION when I navigate back to a page

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am building a UWP app.  On one of my Pages, I keep running into the exception listed in the title.

This is the scenario.  The App loads.  I navigate to my Transit Page (the one that is causing the issue) and it loads fine.  Then I navigate away to another page fine, but when I try to go back to the Transit Page, I hit that unhandled exception in the App.g.i.cs file.
The only message in the exception is: "The parameter is incorrect.\r\n"

I have no idea what is causing this.  If I put a break in the code on my  OnNavigatedTo event in the Transit code behind, it loads the ViewModel, and I hit the error right after this:

```
public ICommand TransitButtonCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _TransitButtonCommand ??
            new RelayCommand(() =>
            {
                _navigationService.Navigate(typeof(TransitView));
             });
    }
 }
```

The only way around this is to put: NavigationCacheMode="Required"  In the Transit view XAML file, but this is not optimal, because this page shows train/bus schedules, and I need it to be updated every time it is loaded.

Any one have any ideas why this is happening?  I am happy to provide anymore code from the project to help with this issue.

My Transit page consists of a SplitView where I load a another XAML page into it based on what menu item is selected.

I created a small project and put it up on GitHub to demonstrate this error, you can find it here:
https://github.com/marekt77/SplitViewBindingTest

Run the App then navigate to the SplitView Page, then away, and then back again, and you will hit the error.

Comment: That's a binding issue. There's something wrong with your XAML. How are you setting the `DataContext` of the page?

Comment: Content="{x:Bind myTransitVM.TransitPage, Mode=OneWay}">

ItemsSource="{x:Bind myTransitVM.AvailableTransitInfo, Mode=OneWay}" 
ItemClick="{x:Bind myTransitVM.TransitOptionsClick}" 
SelectedIndex="{x:Bind myTransitVM.SelectedIndex, Mode=OneWay}" >

Comment: ViewModelLocator myVML = new ViewModelLocator();
myTransitVM = myVML.TransitVM;
this.DataContext = myTransitVM;

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the `SplitViewPageViewModel`. The `PanelPage` property is returning a `Page`. When you first navigate to `SplitViewPage`, it will bind it to the content properly, but on the next time, you're binding it to a new visual tree. The `PanelPage` is still stuck in memory as the child of the first `SplitViewPage` you created. This will throw an exception because that page is a child of another element.

You need to avoid having any UI elements in your view models. They get stuck in memory.

If you have no other option and you just wanna get this thing working, here's a workaround:

```
public class SplitViewPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private INavigationService _navigationService;

    public SplitViewPageViewModel(INavigationService navService)
    {
        _navigationService = navService;
        // construction removed here
    }

    private ICommand _OtherPageCommand;
    public ICommand OtherPageCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _OtherPageCommand ??
                new RelayCommand(() =>
                {
                    _PanelPage = null; // <-- Added this
                    _navigationService.Navigate(typeof(OtherPage));
                });
        }
    }

    private ICommand _HomePageCommand;
    public ICommand HomePageCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _HomePageCommand ??
                new RelayCommand(() =>
                {
                    _PanelPage = null; // <-- Added this
                    _navigationService.Navigate(typeof(HomePage));
                });
        }
    }

    private Page _PanelPage;
    public Page PanelPage
    {
        get
        {
            // build page on demand
            return _PanelPage ?? (_PanelPage = new Views.PanelPage());
        }
        set
        {
            _PanelPage = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("PanelPage");
        }
    }
}
```

The panel page is now created and disposed on demand.

Comment: Thanks for that!  I did implement it at first, but then went a more MVVM route and passed the pages at typeof() Which also works and seems to be the correct MVVM way to do it.  My question is why does passing it as a typeof() work?  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I think because `typeof()` instructs the UI what type of element to instantiate. So it creates a new one every time you bind.